# align divs of unknown contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to align two text divs with undetermined content. Using Bootstrap framework and Wordpress

css

```
#s-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding: 10px 55px;
  z-index: 500;
 }

.main-nav { 
  text-align: right; 
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block; 
  color: #383838;
 }

#copyrite {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<nav id="s-nav" class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" id="s-logo"></a></div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
     <div id="copyrite">| copy 2016</div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

html output

```
<div class="col-sm-4">logo . . . </div>

<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="main-nav">
     <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
       <li id="menu-item-364" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-364">
       <a href="http://localhost/wordpress">HOME</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div id="copyrite">| copy 2016</div>

</div>
```

I want #copyrite to be beside (to the right, vert/horiz align) the menu created with .main-nav

Comment: Show your final html without php, let us know the real structure, plz.

Comment: my aplologies, updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what you want:

```css
.nav-right {
  position:relative;
}
.main-nav {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 25px 65px 25px 0;
}
.main-nav li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.main-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #383838;
}
#copyrite {
  padding: 25px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


<header style="margin-top:30px;">
  <nav id="s-nav" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a href="#" id="s-logo"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 nav-right">
      
      <!-- php echo start -->
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:;">menu1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:;">menu2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:;">menu3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
       <!-- php echo start -->
      
      <div id="copyrite">| copy 2016</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

---

**== UPDATE 1 ==**

Seems css way out is a little hard. However,responsive css will be easy if  getting your html output like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="main-nav">
     <ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
       <li id="menu-item-364" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-364">
       <a href="http://localhost/wordpress">HOME</a>
       </li>

       <!-- try insert #copyright here -->
       <li>
         <span id="copyright">| copy 2016</span>
       </li>

     </ul>
</div>
```

Try to get this by php side:

> I don't have a php run evn now, these code just a guess, hope it works.

```
<?php
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
  return $items .= '<li><span id="copyright">| copy 2016<span></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
?>
<nav id="s-nav" class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4"> <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" id="s-logo"></a></div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <?php wp_nav_menu_items( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
     <div id="copyrite">| copy 2016</div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: the snippet is what I want, but can't seem to get it to work for me

Comment: @user3550879, attention your code `<div id="copyright">` use id and `.copyright` on class.

Comment: Good catch Yin, I have it correct in my code but copied it wrong into the question. #copyrite sits on top of the menu for me

Comment: The way of my solution: make `#copyright` parent node `position:relative`, then it's sibling `.main-nav` padding much more on the right by `.main-nav{padding:25px 65px 25px 0}`, notice that 65px is just a **guess**, should be lager than `#copyright` width. finally, place `#copyright` a absoulte position, by the css code above. add  `padding: 25px 0` to it make it ver align.

Comment: oh, so it's not floating beside, its taking up the space beside it

Comment: Yeah, is floating necessary in your case?

Comment: It is preferable since the site is responsive and user may change content so width may not always stay the same

Comment: @user3550879, updated another way out. hope it works.

Comment: would this not interfere with wordpress and the way it handles its menus? I thought this would be a simple case of having two divs beside each other #copyrite and .menu-nav